# 1.4.4 other 1.5.0 pd.series indexing True auto 0 change

Tags: python, pandas, series

```py
test = pd.Series({True: 0, False: 0})

1.4.4
print(test[0])
> 0

but 
1.5.0
print(test[True])

> keyerror 0
```

1.4.4 and 1.5.0 What has changed?I can't find it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`test[0]` is inherently unclear, and it looks like the updated version of pandas refuses to guess from your ambiguity.

By doing `test[0]` on a Series with a `bool` type index, you could mean:

- `test.iloc[0]`, which is silly, but you should do this explicitly if it's your intention.
- `test[False]` ... remember `0 == False` is `True`.

  - In this case, you should explicitly update code to be clear... `test[bool(0)]`

The `keyerror` is correct though, there is no `0` in `Index([True, False], dtype='bool')`